# When converting primitive data types to Objects, should you cast or create a new object?

Tags: java, casting

This may break the discussion vs. answer rules, but I figure there's a preferred way of doing things.

--

Let's say you need to convert a primitive data type to an Object. Let's use `int --> Integer` as an example. You can do this by casting or straight up making a new Object. For example:

```
int a = 5; int b = 10;
Integer c = new Integer(a);
Integer d = (Integer) b;
```

Which is the better way to do it, `a --> c` or `b --> d`? I suspect they perform the same operation, so which one is usually used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends how it's being used. Most of the time I would just use the `int` wherever I need an `Integer` and let Java auto-box it.

Comment: Neither. Read about autoboxing in java.

Comment: You need neither the cast nor the new. `Integer foo = 3;`

Answer (score 1):

None of the above.
Use `Integer.valueOf` as it yields to significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values.

From the docs of `Integer.valueOf`

> Returns an {@code Integer} instance representing the specified
>        {@code int} value.  If a new {@code Integer} instance is not
>        required, this method should generally be used in preference to
>        the constructor {@link #Integer(int)}, as this method is likely
>        to yield significantly better space and time performance by
>        caching frequently requested values.

But with `autoboxing`, the compiler will do it automatically for you.

```
Integer i = 1;
```

Which is a syntactic sugar for

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say you need to convert a primitive data type to an Object.
>   Let's use int --> Integer as an example. You can do this by casting or
>   straight up making a new Object. For example:

```
int a = 5; int b = 10;
Integer c = new Integer(a);
Integer d = (Integer) b;
```

> Which is the better way to do it, a --> c or b --> d? I suspect they
>   perform the same operation, so which one is usually used?

Java compilers in versions 5 and later perform *autoboxing* to convert between a primitive value and it's corresponding boxed object.  Autoboxing blurs, but does not erase, the distinction between primitive values and objects.

The following line is discouraged:

```
Integer c = new Integer(a);
```

This is because a new object is always created and prevents cached Integer objects from being reused.

This line is transformed by the Java compiler:

```
Integer d = (Integer) b;
```

Instead, this line becomes

```
Integer d = Integer.valueOf(b);
```

This is the code you would get if you omitted the cast from the assignment altogether.  The primitive value is boxed into its corresponding object using the `valueOf()` function.  This is the preferred way to assign primitive values to their objects because this allows the JVM to reuse frequently cached objects.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above.  You can lean on [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) in this scenario to take care of the casts.

That would make your code this:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
Integer c = a;
Integer d = b;
```